# JPA Parent Child works. Insert child alone

Tags: java, mysql, jpa

I am new to JPA. I have parent and several children. I am able to successfully save parent and associated child with Column Mapping using below code.

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "Parent")
public class Parent{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ParentKey", nullable = false, length = 20)
    private Long parentKey;

    @Column(name = "ParentID", nullable = true, length = 60)
    private String parentID;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "ParentKey", nullable = false)
    private Set<Child> childSet = new HashSet<>(0);
}

@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "Child")
public class Child {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long childKey;
    private String ChildID;
}
```

I have a scenario where I receive **only child records with parent ID**. I lookup parent and want to use same child object and repository for saving additional child records. Since there is no reference for parent key, how can I achieve without duplicating child object.

Child Object does not have ParentKey. I do not want to make any changes to Parent when I am loading child records only.

I am using mySQL.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

First, you need a way to query DB that will get you `Parent` entity by `parentID`. If you are using spring data jpa module, you can add the following method to a `ParentRepository`

```
Optional<Parent> findByParentID(String parentID);
```

Assuming your service method looks like this, you first retrieve `Parent` from DB using `parentID` and then you can add children to that parent.

```
public void saveChildren(String parentID, Set<Child> children) {
        Parent parent = parentRepository.findByParentID(parentID)
            .orElseThrow(() -> <Your excp that says parent not found by parentID>);

      // assuming you have filtered out duplicates, now you can save remaining as
      parent.getChildSet().addAll(children);
      parentRepository.save(parent);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. Above will fetch a lot of data from database which I am trying to avoid. In my case, Parent has several Other Child Classes. Since I want to update only one Child, getting entire parent and all its child objects and pushing it back will cause a lot of overhead.